# How to fix "dash.exceptions.NoLayoutException" Error

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to make an aggregate df with the sum of the same values and drop the dates column in the df. Here's my original df:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

raw = [['tom', 10, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['nick', 15, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['juli', 14, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')],['tom', 8, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')],
        ['nick', 4, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')], ['juli', 12, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')]]
df = pd.DataFrame(raw, columns=['Name', 'Apples Gathered', 'date'])

#App layout
app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

layout = html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='datepicker',
        display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
        first_day_of_week=1,
        max_date_allowed=dt.today(),
    ),
])
dash_table.DataTable(
       id='datatable',
       columns=[
            {'id': 'Name', 'name': 'Name'},
            {'id': 'Apples Gathered', 'name': 'Apples Gathered'},
            {'id': 'date', 'name': 'Date'}],

        data = df.to_dict('records'),
)

@app.callback(
       Output('datatable', 'data'),
       [Input('datepicker', 'start_date'),
       Input('date-picker', 'end_date')]
)
def update_table(start_date, end_date):
   dff = (df.groupby(['Name', 'Apples Gathered']).sum())
   return dff.to_dict('records')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When I ran it, i got an error that said:

```
dash.exceptions.NoLayoutException
dash.exceptions.NoLayoutException: The layout was `None` at the time that `run_server` was called.
Make sure to set the `layout` attribute of your application
before running the server.
```

How do I fix the error? I tried uninstalling and re-installing pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Your error was not using app.layout while setting the layout for the dash app. This code works:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

raw = [['tom', 10, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['nick', 15, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['juli', 14, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')],['tom', 8, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')],
        ['nick', 4, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')], ['juli', 12, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')]]
df = pd.DataFrame(raw, columns=['Name', 'Apples Gathered', 'date'])

#App layout
app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='datepicker',
        display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
        first_day_of_week=1,
        max_date_allowed=dt.today(),
    ),
])
dash_table.DataTable(
       id='datatable',
       columns=[
            {'id': 'Name', 'name': 'Name'},
            {'id': 'Apples Gathered', 'name': 'Apples Gathered'},
            {'id': 'date', 'name': 'Date'}],

        data = df.to_dict('records'),
)

@app.callback(
       Output('datatable', 'data'),
       [Input('datepicker', 'start_date'),
       Input('date-picker', 'end_date')]
)
def update_table(start_date, end_date):
   dff = (df.groupby(['Name', 'Apples Gathered']).sum())
   return dff.to_dict('records')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I tried the updated code, however, the issue that I ran into is "No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'", would you know how to get around this issue?

Comment: Although I don't know the exact cause of this issue, after doing a little bit of researching, I have seen that people have fixed this issue by doing `pip install numpy --upgrade`

Comment: I just tried upgrading the numpy installed in my environment, but i'm still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Is it telling you what line the error occurred on?

Comment: It says line 1, that's where that line says: 'import pandas as pd.' On the other line it says: 'ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy'

Comment: Try upgrading pandas the same way you did numpy

Comment: I tried upgrading pandas just now, i'm getting the same error.

Comment: You may want to refer to this https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12825

Comment: It worked! I uninstalled and re-installed both numpy and pandas. Thank you so much